# recover files deleted with rm command in windows

Tags: windows, recovery, data-recovery

I was trying to delete a folder from dekstop that was giving error
on cmd ( windows 7 ) I run

```
cd C:\Users\Chawkii\Desktop

dir /X
```

now trying to run rmdir to delete that path , I accidently forgot to copy the path of that folder and I run the cmd on all dekstop instead

```
rmdir /q s/ C:\Users\Chawkii\Desktop
```

I still have cmd opened and I have names of the files delete ( the results of dir /X) , most of them are txt , images , words + excel + folders , zip

I lost important data like my accounts login credentiels saved in some txt files

I tried some data recovery tools like Recuva & rem recover but it didn't help